# Why can't I access value of a react native state variable inside a function?

Tags: react-native, react-state

I am new to React and am trying to write a very basic counter app. I want to set the value of seconds to 0 if the value is becomes higher than 59 and also increment the minutes by 1. Although the value of seconds does indeed increment in the app, its (seconds) value shows as zero inside the counter function. Why is that so?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native'
import style from "./style"

export default function Timer() {

    const [minutes, setminutes] = useState(0)
    const [seconds, setseconds] = useState(0)

    const counter = ()=>{
        console.log (seconds)
        if (seconds > 59){
            setseconds(0)
            setminutes ((minutes)=> minutes + 1)
        } else {
        setseconds ((seconds)=> seconds + 1)
        }
    }




    return (
        <View style={style.mainContainer}>
            <View style={style.headerContainer}>
                <Text style={style.headerTextMinute} >Minutes</Text>
                <Text style={style.headerTextSecond} >Seconds</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={style.countContainer}>
                <Text style={style.counterTextMinute} > {minutes} </Text>
                <Text style={style.counterTextSpacer} > : </Text>
                <Text style= {style.counterTextSecond}> {seconds} </Text>
            </View>
            <Button title="Start Timer" onPress={()=>{
                setInterval (counter, 1000)
            }} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Try this article https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/

Answer (score 0):

This is a common "problem" of js. I think the console.log shows an outdated version on the timer. Indeed, it shows the state that the setInterval has as a "mental representation" of the state of the app when it was executed. This is not a problem as your app executed as intended.

Anyway, here is another possible solution. Please note that it is important to keep a Ref of your interval in order to be able to terminate it with clearInterval.

```js
function App() {
    const [sec, setSec] = React.useState(0)
    const interval = React.useRef()
    
    const counter = () => {
      if(interval.current){
        clearInterval(interval.current)
        setSec(0)
      }
      interval.current = setInterval(()=>setSec(secs => secs+1), 100)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p> {Math.floor(sec/60)} : {sec%60} </p>
            <button onClick={()=>counter()}>
            {(sec != 0)? "Restart Timer" : "Start Timer"}
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @JeanJacquesGourdin! I don’t believe that it is simply an issue with console.log. In my case the if statement inside counter function never executes because every time counter is called, the value of seconds is 0. There must be something that I am missing here.

Comment: @quasarmarch As I said, i think it depends on the state when the interval is launched. Indeed, if your initial value is let's say "1", your console.log will keep logging 1.  Your counter ref is not updated inside the interval.

Comment: That is very counter intuitive for me. Even when I increment the seconds within the function passed as the first parameter of the setInterval, I still get the same result. What I don’t understand is how is it that I can’t do console.log on the value of seconds (anywhere in the function) except within the return. This beats the purpose if I can’t run conditional statement against the value of the state variables.

Comment: @quasarmarch Javascript is pretty counter intuitive ahah. Moreover, i think here you are in front of two "problems": the closure of the setInterval and the one of the function you give to it. Please try ```setInterval (()=>counter(), 1000)``` instead of ```setInterval (counter, 1000)``` in your code for my knowledge. Anyway you should learn about js closures (as we all do) =)